# Twilio tracking down the phone call statuses

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am making a dashboard to display the client phone numbers phone statuses.
What this means is that assuming that we have a phone number 1234567890, on the dashboard there is a button to invoke an outbound call to another number 9876543210. So I made the feature to track down the phone call status of 1234567890 using Twilio's Sync Map and status call back, following this documentation https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132547-What-do-the-call-statuses-mean-.

However, now I would like to track down the incoming phone call status too. This means that I am making a call from my personal phone to 1234567890, then the incoming call to 1234567890 should be saved in sync map and the status updated should be displayed on the dashboard.

I think the documentation talks only about the outbound calls. And it's quite confusing how to do the incoming calls. I would appreciate if any of you can give some comments on where to start or some feedback if I have a wrong concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get status callback webhooks for incoming calls too. You can set the status callback URL for a nunber in the phone number admin, where you would set the webhook URL for the incoming call too.

[image: fill in the "Call Status Changes" input with your status callback URL]